# vue transition groups with vue2-animate not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transition, animate.css

I've been struggling with making vue transitions work.

I'm using vue2-animate along with vue to create some simple transition effect for when list items appear/disappear.

Here's the block:

```
<transition-group class="mt-2" 
     name="fadeLeft" 
     v-if="type == selectedType" 
     tag="ul">
     <li class="mb-2" v-bind:key="category.name"
         v-for="(category, index) in getCategoriesForType(type)"
         @click="selectCategory(category)">
             {{ category.name }}
     </li>
</transition-group>
```

It doesn't add any effects when I try it. It simply shows/ hides the lists.

I've tested/confirmed that the animation is working in different component, but cannot figure out why the above code doesn't do any animations.

Here's the block that was working:

```
<ul class="list-group notes" v-if="notes.length > 0">
    <transition-group name="fadeLeft">
        <li v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="note" class="list-group-item" v-on:remove="notes.splice(index, 1)">
              <button class="close" @click="removeNote(index)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
              {{ note.text }}
        </li>
     </transition-group>
</ul>
```